# How to invoke asynchronous Bpel Process from OSB

Tags: osb

I have Asynchronous Bpel process and I Want to invoke the same from OSB using the SOA Suite 11g.Can u please suggest me the process.

Answer (score 2):

I recently read a blog on the same, which proved quite helpful to me. Find the link below;

http://biemond.blogspot.com/2009/03/calling-async-bpel-services-from-osb.html

~varun

Comment: Could you give an example from the link you refer to? The link might not live forever

Answer (score 0):

You can use soa-direct protocol.

You can find an example and full explanation in following link:

[OSB 11g - Call Asynchronous SOA service from OSB using soa-direct protocol](http://www.soawork.com/2012/08/call-asynchronous-soa-service-from-osb-using-soa-direct.html)

Short explanation:

```
Use a business service with soa-direct protocol.
Configure it as Role=Asynchronous client.
Configure Callback proxy.

Callback proxy will be the one your BPEL call when finish processing.
```

Comment: Could you give an example from the link you refer to? The link might not live forever

Comment: The link was created in 2012, I think it will live a little longer. It has step by step in how to use soa-direct protocol.

Basically, you need to create a business service with soa-direct procotol, and then configure it as Role=Asynchronous client and Callback Proxy=The proxy where BPEL should respond. This proxy will wait BPEL response.

Comment: you never know, maybe tomorrow they will change link-structure on their site, and suddenly the link doesn't work anymore. Wouldn't be the first time that had happened for a site :)

Comment: I was joking anyway, you are right hahaha I edit the post in order to add a little more info. It will be helpful to guide in the process or at least give a clue what to investigate in order to solve this problem.